# How to merge two multi-dimensional array by its keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I Have two multi dimensional array with same keys. i want to merge these array to one.

```
$sourceData = $array1;
$sourceDataN = $array2;

foreach ($sourceData as $keySd => $sd){

        foreach ($sourceDataN as $keySdn => $sdn){
            if($keySd == $keySdn){
                foreach ($sd as $keySdd => $sdd  ){
                    foreach ($sdn as $keySdnn => $sdnn  ){
                        if($keySdd == $keySdnn){
                           $new[$keySd][] = array_merge($sdd, $sdnn);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


Array (
  [809] => Array
    (
        [ss] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 0
            )

        [bh] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 14
            )

        [li] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 0
            )

        [mg] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 0
            )

    )

  [1944] => Array
    (
        [ss] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 25
            )

        [bh] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 10
            )

        [za] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 10
            )

        [li] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 39
            )

        [mg] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 0
            )

    )

)
Array (
  [809] => Array
    (
        [ss] => Array
            (
                [price] => 603.07
            )

        [bh] => Array
            (
                [price] => 649.95
            )

        [li] => Array
            (
                [price] => 628.48
            )

        [mg] => Array
            (
                [price] => 629
            )

    )

  [1944] => Array
    (
        [ss] => Array
            (
                [price] => 848.7
            )

        [bh] => Array
            (
                [price] => 883.74
            )

        [za] => Array
            (
                [price] => 847.65
            )

        [li] => Array
            (
                [price] => 866.02
            )

        [mg] => Array
            (
                [price] => 847.59
            )

    )

)


Array (
  [809] => Array
    (
        [ss] => Array
            (
                [price] => 603.07
                [qty] => 0
            )

        [bh] => Array
            (
                [price] => 649.95
                [qty] => 14
            )

        [li] => Array
            (
                [price] => 628.48
                [qty] => 0
            )

        [mg] => Array
            (
                [price] => 629
                [qty] => 0
            )

    )

  [1944] => Array
    (
        [ss] => Array
            (
                [price] => 848.7
                [qty] => 25
            )

        [bh] => Array
            (
                [price] => 883.74
                [qty] => 10
            )

        [za] => Array
            (
                [price] => 847.65
                [qty] => 10
            )

        [li] => Array
            (
                [price] => 866.02
                [qty] => 39
            )

        [mg] => Array
            (
                [price] => 847.59
                [qty] => 0
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Array
(
    [809] => Array
        (
            [ss] => Array
                (
                    [a] => 1
                    [b] => 2
                )

        )

)

Comment: If you could provide your sources array and the result you want. We could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have loop on all - just the first array and then goes with the keys to the second one.

You can use simple nested `foreach` loop as:

```
$res = [];
foreach($array1 as $k => $v) { // $k here are the number
    foreach($v as $kk => $vv) { // inner arrays - $kk as 2 char
        $res[$k][$kk] = array_merge($array1[$k][$kk], $array2[$k][$kk]);
    }
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/99HNq)

Comment: I got the answer. Like this

foreach ($sourceData as $keySd => $sd){
    foreach ($sourceDataN as $keySdn => $sdn){
        if($keySd == $keySdn){
            foreach ($sd as $keySdd => $sdd  ){
                foreach ($sdn as $keySdnn => $sdnn  ){
                    if($keySdd == $keySdnn){
                        $data[$keySd][$keySdd] = array_merge($sdd, $sdnn);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Please make that one to one more array section like array => 809

Comment: No sure I follow... (Anyway, left my computer - will elaborate later)